# Error in server programming

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to write a simple code for a server to print something from a function
This code gives me an error :
request for member ‘sin_addr’ in something not a structure or union
and I don't understand why
can you help me?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printsin(struct sockaddr_in *s, char *str1, char *str2) {
  printf("%s\n", str1);
  printf("%s: ", str2);
  printf("%d = ,", s.sin_addr.s_addr);  
  printf(" %d = ", s.sin_port);  
  printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int socket_fd, cc, fsize;
  struct sockaddr_in  s_in, from;
  struct { char head; u_long  body; char tail;} msg;

  socket_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  bzero((char *) &s_in, sizeof(s_in));  /* They say you must do this    */

  s_in.sin_family = (short)AF_INET;
  s_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    /* WILDCARD */
  s_in.sin_port = htons((u_short)0x3333);

  printsin( &s_in, "RECV_UDP", "Local socket is:"); 
  fflush(stdout);

  bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_in, sizeof(s_in));

  for(;;) {
    fsize = sizeof(from);
    cc = recvfrom(socket_fd,&msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fsize);
    //printsin( &from, "recv_udp: ", "Packet from:");
    printf("Got data ::%c%ld%c\n",msg.head,(long) ntohl(msg.body),msg.tail); 
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%d = ,", s->sin_addr.s_addr);  
printf(" %d = ", s->sin_port);
```

That should fix it you pass it in as a pointer then you never deference it.